# Debian 12 Nestopia 1.52.0-1 has bugged default NES gamepad input

Tags: linux, emulation, nes

I installed Nestopia through the official Debian repos (using Debian 12), i.e. `sudo apt install nestopia`. I also have one of those official Nintendo NES gamepads that have the Wii connector, and I have an adapter for PC for that.

I tried playing Mario 1, and noticed that the physical <kbd>B</kbd> button was bound to "turbo jump" while the physical <kbd>A</kbd> button was likely bound to "turbo run", i.e. very rapidly toggling between run and walk. This is despite me going into the configuration menu and attempting to correctly bind <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> to non-turbo.

Note that this is complicated by the fact that there is no obvious way to UNBIND a gamepad key, since if I just click the "turbo A" button, it will hang until I press a key on the gamepad, even if I mash <kbd>Esc</kbd> or any key on my keyboard.

`apt show nestopia` gives this:

```
Package: nestopia
Version: 1.52.0-1
Priority: optional
Section: games
Maintainer: Debian Games Team <pkg-games-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

Answer (score 3):

The described problem is certainly a bug and should probably be fixed by the Debian games team maintainer, but meanwhile here's a workaround.
Going to ~/.config/nestopia/input.cfg, we see this:

```
[gamepad1]
...
js_a=j0b3
js_b=j0b2
js_ta=j0b2
js_tb=j0b3
...
js_softreset=j0b99
js_hardreset=j0b99
```

I just set both `js_ta` and `js_tb` to `j0b99`, because I'm certain that I don't actually have that button on my NES gamepad, and after that everything worked correctly.

As an aside, I noticed that there's really bad input lag. Like maybe 1/5 of a second between pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and Mario jumping. In contrast, when I use the same gamepad on Windows 11 with Nestopia 1.40, it's absolutely perfect with no lag.

(Interestingly, I have the same input lag on FCEUX, which is also in the official debian repo, so I suspect this is a Linux thing, not the emulator's fault. A bit of googling suggests it's due to GNOME having compositor enabled by default.)